# saltstack multiple gitfs_remotes doesnt work

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to add multiple git repos to my salt-master server in order to support all types of servers.
The master file holds:

```
gitfs_remotes:
   - git@REPO_A:
      - pubkey: .....
      - privkey: .....
      - root: salt/
   - git@REPO_B:
      - pubkey: .....
      - privkey: .....
      - root: salt/
```

During testing, both repos are mirrors, they are the same.
So once I add a server to read from salt-master, it reads from REPO A, but then when changing the data in REPO_A in order for the server to read from REPO_B, it gives an error:
No Top file or master_tops data matches found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

found the issue.
 1. /etc/salt/master -> var "top_file_merging_strategy" = merge
 2. cant use default branch "master", i created new branches and i see them under:
 /var/cache/salt/master/gitfs/envs.p

IMPORTANT:
Branches should be unique between all Repositories!!